# Is it possible to create a unique constraint on a sub-key in ArangoDB?

Tags: indexing, model, constraints, arangodb

**Context**

We are limited by ArangoDB's recommendation against using attribute names starting with an underscore  `_` https://www.arangodb.com/docs/stable/data-modeling-naming-conventions-attribute-names.html because we want to be certain that any such attribute would not be used by ArangoDB at a later stage.

We could add an attribute

`properties:{myproperty1:'abc',_myUnderscoreProperty:'def'}`,

but in case we would do this for documents representing users, which would have

`properties:{_name:'abc',_email:'abc@graphileon.com'}`,

we would need to be able to create a unique constraint on `properties._name`. But this does not seem to be possible.

**Question**

Is this possible or there a workaround?

Comment: Why do you think that this is not possible? We have been using unique indexes on sub properties without any issues for several years. How do you create the index? Do you get any errors?

Comment: @mpoeter, I must have overlooked something. It is possible indeed.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. You can create a unique index on field `properties._name`